# Elasticsearch Attachement type not working

Tags: elasticsearch, attachment, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using Windows and `REST API` and have installed the attachment plugin, restarted `elasticsearch` and created the `attachment` property for a particular type in `_mapping`. However, I am getting an error:

I executed this:(NOT WORKING)

```
{
http://localhost:9200/documentsx/person/1(post)
}



{
    "my_attachment" : {
        "_content_type" : "application/pdf",
        "_name" : "/sap1.pdf",
        "content" : "... base64 encoded attachment ..."
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:
:

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal white space character (code 0x20) as character #3 of 4-char base64 unit: can only used between units\n at [Source: [B@16dd7aa; line: 5, column: 29]]; ",
  "status": 400
}
```

BTW if I remove the file or put some random filename above in `_name` it gives the same error, I think it is not reading the file itself.
Where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this error, the value of the "content" attribute needs to be a base64 encoded string. You need to read the contents of the file and convert it to a base64 encoded string and place that string in place of "... base64 encoded attachment ..." above.